# error in my Java

Tags: java, debugging, project

So currently im trying to do a java project and have seen a few answers on this on other websites but im having trouble understandign them. i need to do this:

"Write a program that prompts the user to input a string of words, then counts and displays the number of times each letter in the alphabet appears in the string. It is not necessary to distinguish between uppercase and lowercase letters. Your output should be formatted as follows:

Letter A count = xx
Letter B count = xx
....

Letter Z count = xx"

and this is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Unit9 {




    public static void main(String [] args ) 
    { 
    int array[] = new int[26]; 
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) 
    { 
    array[i] = 0; 
    } 
    Scanner Keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); 
    String userInput; 
    System.out.println("Please enter a string."); 
    userInput = Keyboard.next().toLowerCase(); 
    for (int i = 0; i < userInput.length(); i++) 
    { 
        char ch = userInput.charAt(i); 
        if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') { 
        array[ch - 'a'] ++; 
        } 
    } 
    for (char ch='a'; ch<='z'; ++ch) { 
        System.out.print(ch + array[ch-'a']);

        } 
    } 







}
```

but when i enter "hello" (without the quotes) i end up getting this:

```
Please enter a string.
hello
979899100102102103105105106107110109110112112113114115116117118119120121122
```

what is happening? what am i doing wrong?

EDIT: actually, i just realized something else... it stops detecting when there is a space in the user input meaning that it only detects the first word. how would I add detection for a space as well?

Comment: What are you trying to do with this:  `array[ch - 'a'] ++`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the `+` operator between a `char` and an `int` on this line:

```
System.out.print(ch + array[ch-'a']);
```

This gives you a number as a result, which is then inputted into `System.out.print` taking `int` as input, therefor printing the number itself. You also have no spacing (or use `println`), so it appears to be one long line of numbers.

Try this for your last loop:

```
for (char ch='a'; ch<='z'; ++ch) { 
    System.out.print(ch + ": "+ array[ch-'a']+" ");
}
```

It will now no longer be seen as addition, but rather concatination and show as a string of "letter: amount", one after another for the entire alphabet.

Comment: actually, i just realized something... it stops detecting when there is a space in the user input meaning that it only detects the first word. how would I add detection for a space as well?

Comment: `Scanner` is a tokenizer. You would either have to change the delimiter used by it, or change to some other type of reader, like the `BufferedReader`.

Comment: I am still a beginner at java - how would I change from a scanner to a BufferedReader? Can it do the same style input or do i need to input with a scanner and convert it into BufferedReader?

Comment: This is unfortunately no longer the same problem as you were originally having so you should ask this as a separate problem. First I would look into how it works and make a few attempts to see if you get stuck at something specific.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it only detected the first word is because you entered:

userInput = Keyboard.next().toLowerCase();

instead of

userInput = Keyboard.nextLine().toLowerCase();

nextLine() reads the whole line entered while next() only reads the first word.

Comment: yes thank you - i forgot to close this case because i had solved it with a gentle push in the right direction from Ondkloss - i also noticed this when I rewrote it